# Find the value of $a^2b$ .

Tags: calculus

If a variable tangent to the curve $x^2y = c^3$ makes intercepts $a$ and $b$ on the $x$ and $y$ axis respectively then find the value of $a^2b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tangent in the point $(x_0,\frac{c^3}{x_0^2})$ is $y'=-\frac{2c^3}{x^3}$ so the tangent lines crossing each point of the function are:
$$
y-\frac{c^3}{x_0^2} = -\frac{2c^3}{x_0^3}(x-x_0)
$$
$a$ is where tangent line crosses $x$-axis i.e. $y=0$ , and $b$ is where $x=0$.

$$
\left.
\begin{array}{cc}
y=0 \Rightarrow a &= \frac32 x_0\\
x=0 \Rightarrow b &= 3\frac{c^3}{x_0^2}
\end{array}
\right\}
\Rightarrow a^2b = \frac{27}4c^3
$$

Comment: @BabakS. Thank you dear Babak. This was a recollection of high school calculus for me :D

Comment: I know that  Agha mohandes. :-)

Comment: @BabakS. I know this is a problem for beginners, but solving this easy problem was a breakthrough for me! :D

Answer (score 6):

Hints (yes, **you** fill up the gaps):

$$x^2y=c^3\implies y=\frac{c^3}{x^2}\implies y'=-\frac{2c^3}{x^3}$$

Thus, the tangent line to the above curve on the point $\,\left(m\,,\,\frac{c^3}{m^2}\right)\;$ is

$$y-\frac{c^3}{m^2}=-\frac{2c^3}{m^3}\left(x-m\right)$$

The above line's $\,x-$intercept is

$$x-m=\frac m2\implies \left(\frac32m\,,\,0\right)=(a,0)$$

The above line's $\,y-$intercept is

$$y-\frac{c^3}{m^2}=\frac{2c^3}{m^2}\implies \left(0\,,\,\frac{3c^3}{m^2}\right)=(0,b)$$

Finally

$$a^2b=\frac94m^2\cdot\frac{3c^3}{m^2}$$

which is exactly what you want...

Comment: +1 While reading the post, I was telling to my self that in this answer I wouldn't be face to "..." cause every things go well. But I got them at the end. :D